# Ajax get URL jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to link to an absolute URL vs a relative url. This is ran on a WordPress website and it generates "www.samplewordpress.com/www.domain.com/sample.csv"

I would like it to use "www.domain.com/sample.csv"

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "www.domain.com/sample.csv",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data) {
      var DailyIndex_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
      var table_data = '<table class="table table-striped">';
      for (var count = 0; count < DailyIndex_data.length; count++) {
        var cell_data = DailyIndex_data[count].split(",");
        table_data += "<tr>";
        for (var cell_count = 0; cell_count < cell_data.length; cell_count++) {
          if (count === 0) {
            table_data += "<th>" + cell_data[cell_count] + "</th>";
          } else {
            table_data += "<td>" + cell_data[cell_count] + "</td>";
          }
        }
        table_data += "</tr>";
      }
      table_data += "</table>";
      jQuery("#table").html(table_data);
    },
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the HTTP/HTTPS protocol.

Without a protocol the url will be appended to your current url, hence why you're having that long wrong URL.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://www.example.com/sample.csv",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data) {
      var DailyIndex_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
      var table_data = '<table class="table table-striped">';
      for (var count = 0; count < DailyIndex_data.length; count++) {
        var cell_data = DailyIndex_data[count].split(",");
        table_data += "<tr>";
        for (var cell_count = 0; cell_count < cell_data.length; cell_count++) {
          if (count === 0) {
            table_data += "<th>" + cell_data[cell_count] + "</th>";
          } else {
            table_data += "<td>" + cell_data[cell_count] + "</td>";
          }
        }
        table_data += "</tr>";
      }
      table_data += "</table>";
      jQuery("#table").html(table_data);
    },
  });
});
```

If your AJAX call was in the same domain, you may omit the domain part and make it relative, as per below sample.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "sample.csv",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data) {
      var DailyIndex_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
      var table_data = '<table class="table table-striped">';
      for (var count = 0; count < DailyIndex_data.length; count++) {
        var cell_data = DailyIndex_data[count].split(",");
        table_data += "<tr>";
        for (var cell_count = 0; cell_count < cell_data.length; cell_count++) {
          if (count === 0) {
            table_data += "<th>" + cell_data[cell_count] + "</th>";
          } else {
            table_data += "<td>" + cell_data[cell_count] + "</td>";
          }
        }
        table_data += "</tr>";
      }
      table_data += "</table>";
      jQuery("#table").html(table_data);
    },
  });
});
```

In most modern browsers dev tools (Press F12) you can easily see what's going on from the "Network" tab.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to write the complete URL:

```
http://www.example.com/sample.csv
```

Or at least:

```
//www.example.com/sample.csv
```

Consider for example the following "URLs":

```
www.example.com
example.com
example.html
www.html
com.html
com.html.com
```

How can the browser know what you meant for any given one of these?  Which ones refer to domains and which ones refer to a "file" on the web server?  There's no way for the browser to know for sure.  So the expected behavior is that, unless told otherwise, the browser will consider any such "URL" as relative to the current address.

You instruct the browser otherwise by specifying the `//` root.  If you don't specify the protocol (http, https, etc.) then the browser will default to the protocol used in the current open page.